# Lambda Captures C++14

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I've encountered a notation like:

```
int x = 4;
auto y = [&r = x, x = x+1]()->int { 
    r += 2;
    return x+2;
}();
```

Can you explain this statement? I was a user of C++03 and recently upgraded to C++11. From today I starts C++14 and encountered this snippet.

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Lambda_captures_expressions. There's also a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3610.html) you can look at.

Comment: Wow, this syntax is messed up.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question will ever help anyone else. It's not exactly searchable...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you think the question need a edit to be searchable (adding searchable keywords), you can edit it.

Comment: @KaidulIslam: No, you're the only one who can further explain what part of the code confuses you. Besides, it's _your_ responsibility to post a good question!

Comment: Not sure why this question is being downvoted. Not everyone knows about all the new features C++14 is going to have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks @chris for the [wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Lambda_captures_expressions). What I found is -

[Here is nice explanation who don't know about the old lambda Captures of C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627218/1162233)

In C++14:

---

> C++11 lambda functions capture variables declared in their outer scope
>   by value-copy or by reference. This means that value members of a
>   lambda cannot be move-only types. C++14 allows captured members to be
>   initialized with arbitrary expressions. This allows both capture by
>   value-move and declaring arbitrary members of the lambda, without
>   having a correspondingly named variable in an outer scope.
>
> This is done via the use of an initializer expression:
>
> ```
> auto lambda = [value = 1] {return value;};
> ```
>
> The lambda function `lambda` will return 1, which is what `value` was
>   initialized with. The declared capture deduces the type from the
>   initializer expression as if by `auto`.
>
> This can be used to capture by move, via the use of the standard
>   `std::move` function:
>
> ```
> std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(10));
> auto lambda = [value = std::move(ptr)] {return *value;};
> ```

---

So the above expression updates x to 6, and initializes y to 7.

Comment: I wouldn't say `y` is initialized with `7` since it is a lambda function.

Comment: The lambda is immediately evaluated though, so `y` is initialised.

Comment: If anyone want to give a detailed explanation, please post an answer. I won't accept this answer iff anyone can give some more intuition (as this is my own answer)

Answer (score 1):

This example is part of C++14 feature "Lambda capture Initializers", This allows creating lambda captures initialized with arbitrary expressions.
Using this reference-captures can have different names than the referenced variable.

If you run your code :

```
int x = 4;
auto y = [&r = x, x = x+1]()->int { 
    r += 2; //r=6
    return x+2;//5+2
};
cout<<y()<<endl; // this will print 7
```

Comment: Another example ,With this you will get clear picture.

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
auto x = 1;
auto f = [&r = x, x = x * 10] {
  ++r;
  return r + x;
};
cout<<f()<<endl;
}